# Fade background color of newly added table row

Tags: html, background, html-table, fade

I'm currently trying to add a row to a table, and then fade the background color of the newly added row from red to white, to see which line was just added.

The row is added via:

```
$('#my_table tr:first').after("<tr></tr>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3MCrh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) this will do the trick (assuming the table row gets the class 'highlight'):

```
$('.highlight').effect("highlight", {color:"red"}, 2000);
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Z3C2/1/).

Comment: It's not working in my context. Please take a look at my jsfiddle i've added to my question

Comment: @HappyHacking add this url as external resource and your fiddle will work as well: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js` - the problem is that jQuery UI is not loaded.